# Get list of blob names for failed requests in Azure Monitor log query

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, azure-monitoring

There is a blob trigger function failing, which some are caused by a `System.NullReferenceException`. Is it possible to get the list of blob names that are causing this exception? What would that log query look like? Here is the query I have so far, but not sure where to go from here to get the list of blob names causing the Null Reference Exceptions.

```
requests 
| where success == false
```

[image: End-to-end transaction details]

Answer (score 0):

First, you should query from the `dependencies` table instead of `requests` table.

Then to get failed blob list, you can use the query like below:

```
dependencies 
| where timestamp >ago(7d) // here the time range is set to the latest 7 days, you can change it.
| where success == "false" 
| where type == "Azure blob" 
| project customDimensions.Blob
```

Comment: But how do I filtered by only NullReferenceException?

Comment: @crayden I didn't have the source data, so only provide you some guides on this. You should use [join operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/joinoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer) for `dependencies` table and `exceptions` table, which have the same `operation_Id`. And for `exceptions` table in the join query, you can use `where type="System.NullReferenceException"`.

Comment: @crayden, if the answer is helpful, please help accept it as answer, thanks. And if you still have more questions about this, please let me know.